# Magento, CartController.php, change addAction

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart

I Would like to know the ProductID (in the function addAction()) of the applied product to change the price (discount).

Can someone help me?

```
    // ...
    $cart   = $this->_getCart(); // 
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    $item = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

    foreach($item as $items) {
     $items->getProductId(); // ->doesn't work!!!!!
    }
```

Comment: shufro: Does this help `echo $params['product'];` ? Also before saving cart, you are trying to fetch all cart items

Comment: Thanks, but I also have to change the Price for the product and I do not know how.

Comment: For that you can always use event-observer feature of Magento. You can create an Observer class for the same. More can be seen here - http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

Comment: I can't open the url. Do you know a command (like ->setDiscountPrice or something like that) for a discount price in the shopping Cart?